# Wordpress Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Here is the link to my jsfilddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/np7J7/2/

There, everything works.

When I put what is in jsfiddle into wordpress, I get there error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function"

Chrome says the problem is with the third line here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#SMKT").liScroll();
});
```

I've searched and tried every solution. Nothing seems to work without causing another error. I've disabled any other plugins and jquery stuff that might cause problems.

Answer (score 5):

Wordpress uses jQuery in compatibility mode to avoid using the dollar (which is also used in other frameworks like Mootools).

Use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

So try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("ul#SMKT").liScroll();
});
```

Comment: I tried that already and it doesn't work. Chrome gives me this error when I make that change: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded "

Comment: Then you have another problem also. Changing dollar to jQuery is "harmless". What it did was reveal the next error you have. Your fiddle works with jQuery instead of dollar. So please add more info about your new error and/or make a fiddle that can show the "new" problem

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help - I'm a bit of newb and the fact that the change you suggested worked in fiddle threw me for a loop...

The only other info I can find is chrome says there is an "anonymous function", but it says it's with line 22 in my jsfiddle. This is the line: var width = first.outerWidth(true);

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("ul#SMKT").liScroll();
});
```

the onReady handler receives the jQuery instance as a parameter

Comment: 1+ I like this approach. I have seen that you do similar things with variables throughout most of your answers.

Comment: I tried this, but it produces an error as well. It says there is an "anonymous function", but it says it's with line 22 in my jsfiddle. This is the line: var width = first.outerWidth(true);